# TKINTER EN PYTHON

Tags: python

Hoola me dan un archivo llamado notas.txt
el archivo se ve así:

```
NOTAS;EJERCICIO 1;EJERCICIO 2;EJERCICIO 3;EJERCICIO 4;EJERCICIO
AAAA;2;4;7;2;6;4
BBBB;3;5;5;4;5;5
CCCC;4;6;5;5;4;6
DDDD;5;7;5;6;4;4
```

necesito Abrir y cargar el archivo notas.txt

Usando Tkinter - Mostrar en un dropdown (menuoption)los
nombres de los alumnos

Usando Tkinter - Mostrar todas las notas del alumno y si esta
aprobado o reprobado (aprobado - notas ¿=4,0)

LO QUE TENGO ES LO SIGUIENTE.. PODRIAN DARME UNA MANO PORFAVOR..

```
from Tkinter import*
from ttk import*
ventana=Tk()
ventana.title('Notas')
cuadro1=Frame(ventana)
cuadro1.pack()
cuadro2=Frame(ventana)
cuadro2.pack()
texto=StringVar()

#Abrir el archivo con open('notas.txt', 'r') y luego recorremos cada linea 
# que vamos leyendo
#Luego, despues de la linea 0. Guardamos nuestras notas en el diccionario 
#"notas={}"

#Por cada linea que vaya leyendo, usamos una función que nos separe la linea 
#de su componentes

#LineaComoLista=linea.split(;) y nos quedara algo asi['LLLL', '1', '2', '7']

#Queremos hacer algo como esto: notas['LLLL']=['1', '2', '7']

#Y LineaComoLista[1:]=['1', '2', '7']

#Al final lo que vamos a tener es un diccionario con los nombres de los 
#alumnos y sus notas

#Uno puede acceder a las llaves de un diccionario con notas.keys() -> 
#entrega una lista con los nombres de los alumnos

valores=notas.keys()
menu=OptionMenu(cuadro1,texto,*valores)
subtitulo=Label(cuadro1, text='Notas de alumno', font=(None, 20))
subtitulo.grid(row=1, column=1)
menu.grid(row=2, column=1)
def LeerNotas(*args):
    NombreDelAlumno=texto.get()
    subtitulo.config(text='Notas de' + NombreDelAlumno)
    NumeroDeNotas = 6

    for y in range(0,5):
        etiqueta=Label(cuadro2, text=str(LeerNotas[y]), font=(None, 30), 
relief=RIDGE)
        etiqueta.grid(row=0, column=y, sticky=NSEW)

texto.trace('r', LeerNotas)
ventana.mainloop()
```

GRACIAS

Comment: Hola Soledad, deberías indicar el problema concreto que tienes para que tu pregunta no sea demasiado amplia. Comenta el error que lanza tu código o el resultado no esperado que produce. A primera vista hay un error en tu función `LeerNotas` ya que intentas aplicar indexado sobre una función. El modo de `trace` tampoco creo que sea correcto para lo que buscas.

Comment: Creo que nos estás pegando el enunciado y no lo que has intentado... o la última parte del código es tuya? ¿Qué es lo que no te resulta? ¿Qué sale ahora y qué debiera salir?

Answer (score 0):

Primero debo comentar que tengo prácticamente nula experiencia con `tkinter` así que mi ayuda será incompleta.

Dicho esto, te comento que Python trae incluida la librería `csv` que te permite parsear un archivo como `notas.txt`

```
import csv

notas = {}

with open('notas.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';')
    for linea in reader:
        notas[linea[0]] = linea[1:]

valores = notas.keys()
```

Con eso `notas` es un diccionario que contiene

```
{
    'NOTAS':['EJERCICIO 1', 'EJERCICIO 2', 'EJERCICIO 3', 'EJERCICIO 4', 'EJERCICIO'],
    'AAAA': ['2', '4', '7', '2', '6', '4'],
    'BBBB': ['3', '5', '5', '4', '5', '5'],
    'CCCC': ['4', '6', '5', '5', '4', '6'],
    'DDDD': ['5', '7', '5', '6', '4', '4']
}
```

Y `valores` es un `dict_keys`:

```
dict_keys(['NOTAS', 'AAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCC', 'DDDD'])
```

Tú quieres que al cambiar el selector `menu` se impriman las notas del alumno que figura en el selector. Para eso estás escuchando cuando el valor del texto del selector cambia. Pero en vez de

```
texto.trace('r', LeerNotas)
```

debiera ser

```
texto.trace('w', LeerNotas)
```

porque, de lo contrario, hace falta un segundo click para que se refresquen los datos.

En `LeerNotas` estás trayendo correctamente el `NombreAlumno`, pero no estás trayendo las notas. Me imagino que cuando pones:

```
etiqueta=Label(cuadro2, text=str(LeerNotas[y]), font=(None, 30), 
relief=RIDGE)
```

Ese `LeerNotas[y]` debiera ser la nota obtenida en la asignatura `y`. Pero `LeerNotas` es una función. No una lista. Te falta un paso intermedio para obtener las notas. Por ejemplo:

```
notas_alumno = notas.get(NombreDelAlumno)
for y in range(0, 5):
    etiqueta = Label(
        cuadro2,
        text=str(notas_alumno[y]),
        font=(None, 30),
        relief=RIDGE)
    etiqueta.grid(row=0, column=y, sticky=NSEW)
```

Y con eso tendrás un comportamiento como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probablemente la salida de las notas la necesitas en otro formato (por ejemplo mostrando las asignaturas). Pero eso te lo dejo de tarea, al igual que el determinar si el alumno está aprobado o reprobado.